# How get an exception if {% url 'some-url-name' as the_url %} fails?

Tags: django, django-url-reverse

According to the docs of [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) `the_url` is empty if the reverse of the url fails:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' as the_url %}
```

In my case I would like to get an exception, since I want my tests to fail if my code is broken.

How to store the result of reverse to a variable (and get an exception if the reverse failed)?

Comment: Look at the source code for the `url` tag and write your own version that does raise the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really want to test...

If you only want to test whether "'some-url-name'" can be reversed (regardless of how it's used in templates), the `{% url %}` tag is mainly [a wrapper around `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) so that's easy to unittest.

If you want to test that your urls are correctly reversed *in your templates*, well, the solution is simple: render the template and parse the html to check if the url is ok  ;-)

NB: Django has [some doc on the topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/) and [a couple useful tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/)